# Can't solve this String Issue

Tags: string, python-3.x

We are given a string which has 2 characters - a `W` and a `B`. We need to tell how many W's (Walls) can be broken in such a string. At max, a single B can break 4 W's.

Here is my code for the same:

```
test_cases=int(input())
wallcount1=0

while(test_cases>0):
    bombs=list(input())

    for i in range(0,len(bombs)):
        if bombs[i]=='B':
            if bombs[i+1]=='W':
                wallcount1=wallcount1+1
                bombs[i+1]='0'
           if bombs[i+2]=='W':
               wallcount1=wallcount1+1
               bombs[i+2]='0'

    rever=bombs[::-1]

    for value in range(0,len(rever)):
        if bombs[value]=='B':
            if bombs[value+1]=='W':
                wallcount1=wallcount1+1
                bombs[value+1]='0'
            if bombs[value+2]=="W":
                wallcount1=wallcount1+1
                bombs[value+2]='0'

    test_cases=test_cases-1

    print(wallcount1)
```

Sample input and output are as follows:

> 3
>
> WBW
>
> WWBWWBW
>
> BWWWBWBWW

Output-

> 2
>
> 5
>
> 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two significant issues I see with your code are: you don't reinitialize `wallcount1` in the loop so that one test affects the next; your indexing, `if bombs[i+2]=='W':`, can go beyond the end of the data and cause an index error.  Let's deal with both issues:

The reinitialization of the wall count is easy, move its declaration into the loop.  The index checking can be done in various ways, e.g. check the index you're about to use (e.g. `i + 2`) against the length of the data to make sure you don't go out of bounds.  But, the lazy way is to wrap the code in a `try` clause and let it go out of bounds, catching and ignoring that test result when it does:

```
test_cases = int(input())

for j in range(test_cases):

    wall_count = 0

    characters = list(input())

    for i in range(len(characters)):
        if characters[i] != 'B':
            continue

        try:
            if characters[i + 1] == 'W':
                wall_count += 1
                characters[i + 1] = '0'

            if characters[i + 2] == 'W':
                wall_count += 1
                characters[i + 2] = '0'
        except IndexError:
            pass

    characters = characters[::-1]

    for i in range(len(characters)):
        if characters[i] != 'B':
            continue

        try:
            if characters[i + 1] == 'W':
                wall_count += 1
                characters[i + 1] = '0'

            if characters[i + 2] == 'W':
                wall_count += 1
                characters[i + 2] = '0'
        except IndexError:
            pass

    print(wall_count)
```

Note that we can double up the tests within the `try` clauses because if the `i + 1` test causes an exception, there's no point in trying the `i + 2` test.

Comment: Thanks for answering@cdlane.but for a few test cases the output is not correct.I just ran the code

Comment: 5
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB
BWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBBBBBBBBBB
WWWWWWWBBWWBBWWBBWWBWBWBW

Comment: 10
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
BWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB
BBWBWBWBWB
BWBWB
BWBWBWB
BWBWBWBWBWBWBBWBWBWWBBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWB
BWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBWBBBBWBBWBWWBWWWBWBBB
WBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBWBWBWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBWWBWBWBWB

Comment: The other 2 inputs are huge(1000 characters or so)

Comment: @DhruvMarwha, try it again.  I failed to account for Python's negative indexes so I went back to your original design to fix that issue.  The two significant issues I mentioned are still the same.

Comment: The logic i had used was also the same but i didn't knew how to solve the out of bounds index error.Thanks for helping out.